# Avaje Ebean: Why does it insert object with same ID instead of updating the object?

Tags: java, ebean

I am learning ebean, to start I am testing the code of examples on the official site, so I have this code:

```
ESimple e = new ESimple();  
e.setName("test");  
e.setDescription("something");  

// will insert  
Ebean.save(e);  

e.setDescription("changed");  

// this will update  
Ebean.save(e); 

// find the inserted entity by its id  
ESimple e2 = Ebean.find(ESimple.class, e.getId());  
System.out.println("Got "+e2.getDescription());  

Ebean.delete(e);
```

ESimple is this simple class:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="e_junktable")
public class ESimple {

    @Id 
    Integer id;  

    String name;  

    String description;  

    @Version  
    Timestamp lastUpdate;

    // getters, setters

}
```

Running the code above I get that error from the logs:

```
txn[1003], 15:32:11.019, insert into e_junktable (id, name, description) values (?,?,?) 

txn[1003], 15:32:11.019, Binding Insert [e_junktable]  set[id=1, name=test, description=something, ] 

txn[1003], 15:32:11.024, Inserted [ESimple] [1] 

txn[1004], 15:32:11.024, insert into e_junktable (id, name, description) values (?,?,?) 

txn[1004], 15:32:11.024, Binding Insert [e_junktable]  set[id=1, name=test, description=changed, ] 

txn[1004], 15:32:11.039, ERROR executing DML bindLog[Binding Insert [e_junktable]  
set[id=1, name=test, description=changed, ]] error[Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_C ON PUBLIC.E_JUNKTABLE(ID)"; SQL statement:\n insert into e_junktable (id, name, description) values (?,?,?) [23505-170]]
```

The error is on the second `Ebean.save(e)`.

It seems that it doesn't update the object in the database but instead it tries to insert a new one with the same id, why?

I am using ebean 2.7.7, h2 1.3.170 as database.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you could get this if the bean was not enhanced and you didn't have a @Version property - but you do.

So, not sure. You could try using a debugger and seeing why the second insert is treated as such (not an update) or you could confirm the same behavior with the latest Ebean

Comment: I was missing to enhance the classes. Thanks for the help.